# I create the first bot and a warning comes out / local variable chat_id value is not used

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.utils import executor

 bot: Bot = Bot(token='TOKEN')
 dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler()
async def get_message(message: types.Message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    text = "shiz ?"


 sent_message = await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=text)

 print(sent_message.to_python())


 executor.start_polling(dp)
```

#local variable "chat_id" value is not used
#local variable "text" value is not used

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix your function to be as such:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def get_message(message: types.Message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    text = "shiz ?"
    sent_message = await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=text)
    print(sent_message.to_python())
```

Placing the send_message and print inside the get_message in order to make use of the chat_id and text